# Dynamically creating modal windows with Semantic UI and Angular2 - DOM error

Tags: angular, dom, semantic-ui

I am experiencing a problem with Angular2 combined with the Semantic UI framework. I'm trying to make a dynamically created child view to show a modal window.
The problem occurs when the template for my modal utilizes Semantic UI; the DOM element known by Angular suddenly disappears.

Currently I have a parent ts component:

```
export class TableComponent implements onInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
...
@ViewChild('TestModal', { read: ViewContainerRef }) testModal: ViewContainerRef;
...
    if(this.componentRef) {
        this.componentRef.destroy();
    }
    let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(testModalComponent);
    this.componentRef = this.testModal.createComponent(factory);
...
}
```

and the template which amongst other include:

```
<div #CompetitorModalComponent></div>
```

In the modal component everything works fine if I only use paragraph tags, etc. but whenever I want to use Semantic's modal

```
<div class="ui long first coupled modal fullscreen" id="testModal"></div>
```

the DOM element no longer appears like "app-test-modal" but rather it appears inside a div which Angular has no control over / the Angular DOM element is gone.

My problem is, that I can no longer delete the child component using the .destroy()-method, which normally wouldn't be a problem. Any suggestions how to work around this, so I can actually delete the generated components dynamically (without having to manipulate the DOM manually),

thanks!